# arrayList<File> to folder containing those files java

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<File>`.

And I need to write those files into a output_Directory into my computer

this is my code

```
for (File file : corpus)


{ 
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (new File(outDirName, file.getName()));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (bw);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

the corpus is the arraylist of files

the error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Diroutput/name of my file
```

(no files or directories of this types)

Comment: What do you deduce from the name, message, and javadoc of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working
    File dir= new File(outDirName);
            if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();}

```
            for (File file : corpus)
            { 
          File new_file= new File(dir,file.getName());  
                {
                if(!new_file.exists()){
                    new_file.createNewFile();
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your output directory doesn't exist. So create the output directory first and the error is gone. Also, you can use `Files.copy()` from `java.nio.file` which will avoid to create multiple FileWriter instances

```
try {
    Files.copy(
        Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()),
        Paths.get(new File("<correct Path>", file.getName()).getAbsolutePath()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```